# How to get row count using LINQ on a file

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Code so far:

```
var lines = from rawLine in File.ReadLines(readFolderFile, Encoding.Default) where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine.Trim(';')) select rawLine;
```

But now I also need in the first "colum" of my IEnumerable the row count. I tried to adapt from other people who had a more or less similar problem but never got it to work so far.

I tried "solutions" like:
[How do you add an index field to Linq results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269058/how-do-you-add-an-index-field-to-linq-results) ,
[Get record's row number using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952882/get-records-row-number-using-linq)
 and some other ones. I do unterstand, that I need some kind of index, but I dont understand where do I add my `.Select(()=> )`

What I tried and obsiously doesnt work is:

```
var lines = (from rawLine in File.ReadLines(readFolderFile, Encoding.Default) where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine.Trim(';'))
            select rawLine).Select((rawLine, index) =>  index++, rawLine);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query syntax doesn't provide the overload of [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) (and `Where`) with the index. So you need to use method syntax.

If you also want to count empty lines but don't include them in the result, select the anonymous type before the `Where` otherwise after:

```
var linesAndLineNumbers = File.ReadLines(readFolderFile, Encoding.Default) 
   .Select((line, index) => new { Line = line.Trim(';'), LineNumber = index + 1 })
   .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Line));
```

> is there a way, where I could get the result as Line = {Line =
>   "LineNumer;colum1;colum2;columnX..."}

Sure:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(readFolderFile, Encoding.Default) 
   .Select((line, index) => new { Line = line.Trim(';'), LineNumber = index + 1 })
   .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Line))
   .Select(x => $"{x.LineNumber};{x.Line};");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I also saw already  with my approach I forgot to use the "new" statement but as a result with this or my version I get this: _{ Line = "colum1;colum2;columX...", LineNumber = X } <Anonymous Type>_ is there a way, where I could get the result as Line = _{Line = "LineNumer;colum1;colum2;columnX..."}_

Comment: one more question, is there also the way that I first select only the first row add something like RowNumber as a column name and after that start counting or do I have to it in two steps, with something like `.First()`?

Comment: @HakunamaTatarov: sorry, i dont' understand your question

Comment: no problem, I try to explain it a bit different. right now with the last solution you get as the column name "1" because it starts couting from line 1. but instead of 1 im trying to write RowNumber. Because the first row in every file I read include the column names.

Comment: @HakunamaTatarov: well, `$"RowNumber{x.LineNumber};{x.Line};"`

Comment: this is what I got so far ` var lines = ..... .Select(x => $"RowNumber;{x.Line};").First();  var lines2 = ..... .Select(x => $"{x.LineNumber};{x.Line};").Skip(1);` And then I guess there is some method to concat both IE<strings>.

Comment: @HakunamaTatarov: why `First`? You don't need to concat the first and the rest

Comment: hm I cant really follow this syntax then. x.LineNumber is the LineNumber of the "dataset" x and x.Line is the information of this "dataset". If I understand this correct. But Im not really a developer or still learning, I dont see how to manipulate the term `$"RowNumber{x.LineNumber};{x.Line};"` to get what I want, but I'll search a little more, thanks for helping so far :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179560/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-hakunama-tatarov).

Answer (score 2):

You indeed need to use Select, and then just to store the index.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(readFolderFile, Encoding.Default)
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine.Trim(';')))
    .Select((x, i) => new
    {
        Line = x,
        Index = i
    }
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This answer doesn't count empty lines, Tim's does incremet the counter - no idea what OP wants so just mentioned